# How efficient is SBCL for storing big graphs?

Tags: c, graph, sbcl, ffi

How much does the garbage collector affect performance when working with lots of objects in memory, how big is the memory allocation and dealocation overhead?
Is it wise to use SBCL to do this or is better to build a small C library to connect trough FFI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you have done is allocate, then you will just have a small (a few bytes) of overhead per object. If the system has done a variety of allocations and deallocations, as a general rule external fragmentation results in about as much wasted space as used space, or a 100% overhead.